# Tooltip truncated in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, tooltip, truncate

I have a unique scenario in a JQgrid here. I am trying to load some data into jqGrid. The data is successfully loaded into the grid. The issue is when i hover on a particular column of a row the tooltip appears. I am able to see all the tooltip which has a normal text but when the text has a "<" character to tooltip gets truncated hence entire text isn't visible. Could you please suggest ??

Comment: got the solution .... simply replace "<" with "&lt;". It will work.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you didn't used the option `autoencode: true` which is **strictly recommended** if you can't guarantee that the texts in grid don't contains special characters used in HTML.

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/TooltipWithSpecialCharacters.htm):

[image]

Comment: Hello Oleg, link given here redirects to other demo, please update the link.

Comment: @ITppl: You are right. I unanswered on many questions at the same time. I updated the link to the demo. In general [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/TooltipWithSpecialCharacters.htm) has no important code other as the option `autoencode: true` which I described in the answer.